# Is `Array.prototype.reduceRight` identical to `reverse` followed by `reduce`?

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, reduce

[`Array.prototype.reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceright) reduces an array to a single value, working right-to-left (i.e. starting from the end of the array).

Is calling `reduceRight` exactly the same as calling [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) followed by [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)? If so, why does `reduceRight` exist?

Comment: It's not the same, reverse reverses the array *in place*, whereas reduceRight does not mutate the original.

Comment: Reverse is in-place method, where reduceRight isn't

Answer (score 4):

[`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) is *not* the same as [`Array#reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) -> [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Here is the key difference `.reduce()`/`.reduceRight()` do not modify the starting array:

```js
const arr = ["a", "b", "c"];

const combine = arr.reduceRight((a, b) => a+b, "");

console.log(combine);
console.log(arr);
```

However, `.reverse()` does:

```js
const arr = ["a", "b", "c"];

const combine = arr.reverse().reduce((a, b) => a+b, "");

console.log(combine);
console.log(arr);
```

There is also question for a performance - `.reverse` will incur an additional `O(n)` processing to reverse the array in-place, that's on top of the `.reduce()` that already operates at `O(n)`. Yes, the final complexity is still `O(n)` (we ignore the constants) but having a single pass through the array is faster.

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned, it is not the same. Here are two more use cases, where those two versions behave differently:

- Everything that is based on the index (third argument of the callback function called by both `reduce` and `reduceRight`) might behave differently.
- Reverse loops are often used when the *original* array is being modified. Depending on the exact use case, that might work with `reduceRight` but break with `reduce`.

Comment: I didn't think of the indexes being different between the two, but you are absolutely correct. This itself is a difference enough that would make it so `reduceRight()` and `reverse().reduce()` would be completely incompatible even if `reverse` produced a new array without modifying the original.

Answer (score 1):

It already was mentioned that `.reverse()` modifyes iinitial array,

In addition, according to spec:

https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.reduce

https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.reduceright

Implementations are a bit different.

Let me allow the analogy with `.push()` and `.unshift()` - they do also quite a same, inserting an element in array, we use push a lot, and unshift quite rarely, but time to time there are some perfect moments for `unshift` as well as for `reduceright`